# Django management command and argparse

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a Django management command with argparse, however whenever I run it, it always returns *no such option* which is valid, as this message comes from the manage.py:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Parsing arguments')
        parser.add_argument('--max', type=float, store)
        args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[2:])
```

What would be the right way to use some argument parser with management commands?

Python version 2.x .

Comment: It's worth noting that Django now uses argparse instead of optparse as of Django 1.8 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 13):

In Django options are parsed with rules given in `add_arguments` method of `BaseCommand`. You should add your options to `parser.add_argument`, which use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) lib like this:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'My cool command'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        # Named (optional) arguments
        parser.add_argument(
              '--max',
               action='store',
               dest='max',
               type='float',
               default=0.0,
               help='Max value'
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print options['max']
```

Comment: Thanks, it' s fine, however a comma is missing. For later usage, can You please add it?

Answer (score 5):

Instead, just modify the `option_list`, [as suggested in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/):

```
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--max',
            action='store',
            type='float',
            dest='max'), 
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print options['max']
```

Comment: I think a comma and a parenthesis is missing from your code... . Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#accepting-optional-arguments), custom options can be added in the add_arguments() method.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        # Positional arguments
        parser.add_argument('poll_id', nargs='+', type=int)

        # Named (optional) arguments
        parser.add_argument(
            '--delete',
            action='store_true',
            dest='delete',
            help='Delete poll instead of closing it',
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # ...
        if options['delete']:
            poll.delete()
        # ...
```